# offending line docker_container: name:db

Tags: docker, ansible

What's wrong with the bellow tasks in for ansible docker_container

```
- name: "Create container for database"
  docker_container: 
      name: db 
      image: "postgres:latest"
      state: started
      volume:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
      env:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "{{ lookup('password', '../files/dbpassword.txt') }}"

- name: "Create container for app"
  docker_container:
      name: botsystem
      image: "ubuntu:latest"
      state: started
      volume:
      - /opt/bot
      env:
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "{{ lookup('password', '../files/dbpassword.txt') }}"
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
>
> The error appears to have been in
>   '/home/xxx/workspace/ansible/main-server/roles/docker/tasks/main.yml':
>   line 3, column 1, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the
>   exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> docker_container:     name: db ^ here

Did serveral editions of this using sublime text instead of vim and overcame that error also with the change of volume to volumes

```
- name: "Create container for database"
  docker_container:
    name: db 
    image: "postgres:latest"
    state: started
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    env:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "{{ lookup('password', '../files/dbpassword.txt') }}"


- name: "Create container for app"
  docker_container:
    name: botsystem
    image: "ubuntu:latest"
    state: started
    volumes:
      - /opt/bot
    env:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "{{ lookup('password', '../files/dbpassword.txt') }}"
```

Now I have error:

> ERROR! no action detected in task
>
> The error appears to have been in
>   '/home/xxx/workspace/ansible/main-server/roles/docker/tasks/main.yml':
>   line 1, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the
>   exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> - name: "Create container for database"   ^ here

Comment: Maybe the indentation?

Comment: Tryed already correcting it , but it only pointed the error to another thing

Comment: Try changing `volume` by `volumes` or `volumes_from` may [this link](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/docker_container_module.html) helps you

Comment: Which version of ansible are you using?

Comment: I was using the one from ubuntu 16.04 LTS , after that I added the ppa for ansible and am using 2.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add `---` at the beginning of the file? Also change `volume` by `volumes`.

Something like:

```
---

- name: Create container for database
  docker_container: 
    name: db 
    image: "postgres:latest"
    state: started
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    env:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "{{ lookup('password', '../files/dbpassword.txt') }}"

- name: Create container for app
  docker_container:
    name: botsystem
    image: "ubuntu:latest"
    state: started
    volumes:
      - /opt/bot
    env:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "{{ lookup('password', '../files/dbpassword.txt') }}"
```

Comment: No, I have other main.yml that runs without it, I tried adding it to see if it would work  and didn't.

Comment: - name: "Create container for app"
    docker_container:
    ^ here

After redoing tabs and all, fails there now.

Comment: And if you remove th `"` character from the name? Look at my upadted answer

Comment: Yes, but happens the same thing. It complains of the first line have it be the --- or no, also tried removing the "

Comment: Going to delete this, the problem was that I was using ansible < 2.1 and to use docker_container it requires ansible >= 2.1 , this error messages need to be improved.

Comment: I placed your answer has correct, for the correction of the "volume" keyword.